# How to add the value of one column in table B to another column in table A by joining by email

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I'm updating the question with a bit more specifics because I can see there are too many further questions:

1. All the rows in Table B are in Table A.
2. Table A has more rows than Table B.

---

I have a Points column in Table A and another Points column in Table B.

I want to join the tables by email address and then update the Points column in Table A with B if Points has no value in Table A.

Also if there is a value in A.Points, I want the new value of A.Points to be the sum of A.Points and B.Points.

I used this query but I got an error on line 3.

I tried a plus sign and that ended up changing way more rows than when I did a select query beforehand to check how many rows would be  affected.

```
select tableA.email, tableA.points, tableB.points from tableA left join tableB on tableA.email = tableB.email
```

```
update tableA
left join tableB on tableA.email = tableB.email
set tableA.points = sum(tableA.points,tableB.points)
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want `tableA.points = tableA.points + tableB.points`, but I'd be wary of the fact that you may end up double-counting points of `tableB` if it isn't cleared. Perhaps you in fact want a view/temptable which will hold the sum of the two for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your current approach:

1. You are using `sum` to add the values, but `sum` is an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html). You can read a bit on the documentation the use cases it applies for but that is not how its used. What you want is a simple mathematical operation of summing two values, so you should get that with a simple `+`:

```sql
update table_a
left join table_b on table_a.email = table_b.email
set table_a.points = table_a.points + table_b.points;
```

2. You also mentioned this part below, and this will not be done in that same update, that will only add values that already exist.

> and then update the Points column in Table A with B if Points is empty in A.

I am not sure what you mean by "is empty in A". If you mean the points are `null` in A for that email then you can just run a second update like:

```sql
update table_a
left join table_b on table_a.email = table_b.email
set table_a.points = table_b.points
where table_a.points is null;
```

But if you mean that the record with that email does not exist on table A then you will need to `insert` the new records like:

```sql
insert into table_a
select b.points, b.email 
from table_b b 
where b.email not in (select email from table_a);
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecb5c9

**Observation:** as Rogue mentioned on the comments, you might want to check if that is really what you want, since each time you run the updates you will be readding the B value into A, which can very easily turn into double counting. In that same note if you run the update to consider the `null` values, that **needs** to happen **after** the first update, else you will also be directly double counting the points.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't quite follow how it will double count. I'm going to run the query (I have made a backup) and see the results to try and understand this.

Comment: It would double count if you run it twice. If on table A you have 5 points for email "a@a.com" and on table B you have 3 points for the same email, when you run your update you will have 8 points on table A, right? But if you run the update again for some reason then you will count again and have 11 points on table A. The point is that you don't have the original data that resulted in the 8 in the first place because you override it, so there's no way to recalculate or confirm.

Comment: As for the null value lets say you have email "a@a.com" with points = null on table a, and 5 points on table B. If you run first the update for null values, table a will be updated to have 5 points. If you run the other update after that, the one that gets existing values and sums them up, it will update that record on table a to have 10 points, double counting the points. Makes sense?